# Python: How do I satisfy either or of two completely different conditions in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I wanted to have a while loop that takes in a string of either only numbers, the string "value", or string "v". I tried doing :

```
num = input('type a number, "value", or "v". ')
while num.lower() not in ["value", "v"] or num.isdigit() != True:
    num = input("Can only input numbers or 'value' or 'v'. please try again ")
if num.lower() == "value" or num.lower() == "v":
    print("Great you want a value!")
elif num.isdigit() == True:
    print(f"Your number is {num}")
```

This does not work because it goes into an infinite loop of asking me to input again. I believe it's because the while loop wants to satisfy both conditions but can't. Any way to retype the while conditions or suggestions on a different approach?

Comment: You need to consistently *call* the methods.

Comment: `num.lower()` is very different than `num.lower`. Adding the parenthesis `()` lets the function run. If you don't add them, you are just talking about or referring to the function, not actually letting it run. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I was typing fast. I'll edit it. I was having the same issue after calling it as well. Any idea?

Comment: The problem is that you're using `or` in the while loop.  If they type "value" or "v", `num.isdigit()` is false; and if they type a digit, it is not equal to "value" or "v".  Use `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: Hi John Gordon, The and fixed it. Care to explain why this work? Shouldn't the and ask for both statements to be true? Thank you

Comment: Both of your conditions are negations (i.e. `not in` and `!=`), so using `and` to join them makes the loop continue while you _don't_ have a valid input.  If either negation is false, then you _do_ have a valid input, and so the loop stops.

Comment: This is great to know, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to prompt for it twice, and you needed an "and" not an "or". Try this:

```py
num = ''
while num.lower() not in ["value", "v"] and num.isdigit() != True:
    num = input("Can only input numbers or 'value' or 'v'. please try again ")
if num.lower() == "value" or num.lower() == "v":
    print("Great you want a value!")
elif num.isdigit() == True:
    print(f"Your number is {num}")
```

Comment: Hi Chris, The and worked! Thank you. Can you explain why? Wouldn't "and" have both conditions be True to break the loop?

Comment: @Alejandro This is because you were telling to repeat the while loop as long as `num` was not a number, or if `num` was not "v" or "value". This means that even if you type "v", it will repeat because it wasn't a number. And if you type a number, it will repeat because it wasn't "v" or "value.". The reason we need an `and` is because we want it to repeat if num satisfies the following: It's not a number, *and* not in ["value", "v"]. (You could've also instead put a `not` at the beginning which is what I did.)

Answer (score 1):

You're while loop needed a little editing.

I changed: `while num.lower() not in ["value", "v"] or num.isdigit() != True:` to `while not ((num.lower() in ["value", "v"]) or (num.isdigit() == True)):`

**Now it works.** You can type "v", "value", or any number:

```py
num = input('type a number, "value", or "v". ')
while not ((num.lower() in ["value", "v"]) or (num.isdigit() == True)):
    num = input("Can only input numbers or 'value' or 'v'. please try again ")
if num.lower() == "value" or num.lower() == "v":
    print("Great you want a value!")
elif num.isdigit() == True:
    print(f"Your number is {num}")
```

Comment: Really all I did was put a `not` at the beginning. But I also added more parenthesis so that it would be easily understood and readable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `num.isdigit`. It is a *function*, and you don't call it. So, you are not evaluating *the returned value of the function, but the function itself*.
In python functions evaluate to `True`, so `while num.isdigit != True` will never terminate.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response, I typed this quickly but in the original code it was being called and I was getting the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- The problem was that you didn't `call` any methods but just passed
  them. You have to call them like: `object.method()` and not like `object.method`
- Also update your while `condition` to this: `num.lower() in ["value", "v"] or num.isdigit() == True`. Now it will work as you wish.

Whole code:

```
num = "value" #We can start with this value

while num.lower() in ["value", "v"] or num.isdigit() == True:
    num = input("Can only input numbers or 'value' or 'v'. please try again ")

    if num.lower() == "value" or num.lower() == "v":
        print("Great you want a value!")
    elif num.isdigit() == True:
        print(f"Your number is {num}")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The point of the while loop is to force the user to select either "value", "v", or a str(number). This will just keep looping over and over after adding an input.

Comment: Hi no it won't :) If you type anything different then "value" / "v" / number the `while` loop will stop. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is set wrong. The first condition is always satisfied when you input an integer:

This:

```
num = input('type a number, "value", or "v". ')
while num.lower() not in ["value", "v"] or num.isdigit() != True:
    print(num.lower() not in ["value", "v"])
    print(num.isdigit() != True)
    num = input("Can only input numbers or 'value' or 'v'. please try again ")
if num.lower == "value" or num.lower == "v":
    print("Great you want a value!")
elif num.isdigit == True:
    print(f"Your number is {num}")
```

returns this:

```
type a number, "value", or "v". 4

True
False
Can only input numbers or 'value' or 'v'. please try again
```